# C# Update command with oledb

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledbcommand

I'm trying to update the selected row in access database. How do I Update selected row in my access database?

I've tried using the update command

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dataRes.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string a = "Cancelled";
                DataGridViewRow dr = dataRes.Rows[i];
                if (dr.Selected == true)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Reservation SET Status ='" + a + "' WHERE ID = " + i +" ";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Reservation Cancelled");

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I'd supose dr.Selected == true  is always false. You should set a breakpoint there.

Comment: Are you sure the primary key for Reservation is the same as the index i? It doesn't sound likely. You probably need to locate your reservation key out of your rows, rather than using the index. And as an aside, you would be better to create and open your connection once, and use a parameterised query that you also only create once, rather than once for each row.